# I get blackscreen after boot in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login

So today I woke up and couldn't log in into my user (the screen flashed and went back to the login screen), following advise elsewhere I deleted .Xauthority. Now I just get a black screen, I can only use tty's. I reinstalling unity but it also didnt work.

Edit: I installed gdm and it also doest load. It just shows the ubuntu loading screen forever.

Comment: Can you log in as an other user, e.g. the guest account?

Comment: No. Also I just reinstalled the whole system, and after update, exact same thing

Comment: Do you see any relevant errors in "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"?

Comment: Not any more. I reinstalled once more, it might be an issue with the new login system so I'll just wait a few days before updating.

Comment: If you use btrfs for the install you can snapshot your system before the update and then rollback if it does not work. No need to re-install. Your problem sounds like [bug #1283826 
lightdm hangs after updates](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1283826)

Comment: It does sound like it, but why would it suddenly show up? Also, is there any way around it?

Comment: My computer doesn't boot to a blackscreen. It boots to the login screen. It just gives me a blackscreen after that.

Comment: `grep "] (EE)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows you the errors of the X server. `tail /var/log/syslog` displays general problems. Add some logfile output to your question, please.

Comment: As I said. I just reinstalled a second time. I could do the upgrade tomorrow and get the logs after it breaks again. How can I avoid reinstalling yet again if it breaks again?